# Using grep to filter output of a process

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I'm using `command | grep -v "JavaScript strict warning"` to filter the output of a command (hiding warnings). The grep command works fine when I test it like this:

```
$ printf "JavaScript strict warning: warning\nNot a warning\nJavaScript strict warning: warning\nJavaScript strict warning: warning\n" | grep -v "JavaScript strict warning"
```

The output is:

```
Not a warning
```

However, when I filter the running output, lines with `JavaScript strict warning` still come through. I believe that it's happening because the original command is spawning another process. Is there a way to keep filtering the output of the new process?

Comment: the output you see may be stdout and stderr, but a pipe only passes on stdout.

Comment: @MaQleod is there a way to know if it's stderr? Is there a way to pass stderr to another pipe?

Comment: Actually, just figured it out. I added ```3>&1 1>&2 2>&3``` before the pipe, and everything works. Thanks for the correct diagnosis! If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the output you see is likely stderr - a pipe only passes on stdout by default.

As you noted in your comment you can use redirects to adjust what gets passed on.